# How do I bring raw map data to Google Maps overlay/layer?

Tags: google-maps

I wish to develop a mobile app (probably on Android) that plots disabled parking spots block by block on Google Maps. Given that the appropriate city/government agencies will most likely provide this data in some sort of paper printout of maps, how do I migrate this to a overlay/layer for Google Maps?

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you need the coordinates of each one of the points you wish to mark using an overlay

Comment: Okay. What if the map I receive is an actual print out of the map of the city - how do I get those drawn points onto a Google Map [overlay/layer]?